# Anime/cartoon where gray men chase a homeless girl

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remembered the other day a TV show about a homeless girl making people around her happy and some pale men chasing the kid. Here are some key features from before and after she went missing and came back:

Before going missing:

Certain Info:

1. She had friends (other children)
2. The men chasing her were causing problems for citizens, they smoked cigars/cigarettes and had gray skin and there was nothing colorful about them or their cars (I think they had cars)

Uncertain info:

1. I think she had bobbed short hair, dark in color, she wore a long jacket/raincoat probably yellow
2. the men were very similar with minimal difference between them

Something happened to her and she was summoned to heaven? I cant recall exactly but an old man with a turtle talked to her and sent her back to earth. However this trip took quite some time and now a few years passed (maybe just one I don't remember)

After she got back:

1. One of her friends became a celebrity and has no time for 'friends'
2. That celebrity child is being told incorrect info: his friends left him and so on
3. Everyone in town is in a hurry and ignores the girl as she looks for her friends
4. People who have an encounter with her stop rushing and their stress disappears
5. Somehow she ends up in the gray men headquarters and finds an odd room with flowers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the description, I think the story is an adaptation of the book [Momo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(novel)) by Michael Ende.
There was a movie, also called [Momo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(1986_film)), 1986 that might match.
Wikipedia describes it like this

> In the ruins of an amphitheatre just outside an unnamed Italian city lives Momo, a little girl of mysterious origin. She is remarkable in the neighbourhood because she has the extraordinary ability to listen—really listen. By simply being with people and listening to them, she can help them find answers to their problems, make up with each other, and think of fun games.
>
> This pleasant atmosphere is spoiled by the arrival of the Men in Grey. These strange individuals represent the Timesavings Bank and promote the idea of timesaving among the population, time which can be deposited to the Bank and returned to the client later with interest. In reality, the more time people save, the less they have. The time they save is actually lost to them, consumed by the Men in Grey. Momo, however, is a wrench in the plans of the Timesaving Bank thanks to her special personality.

Comment: Notably the film wasn't animated, but it certainly has a cartoonish look and feel.

Comment: Yes this is it, and I already found the show banner thx.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(2001_film)

Comment: @LogicDictates - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS9HTbNJfmk the trailer for the animated version shows the turtle about a minute in

Comment: There is also an animated TV series: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_(Zeichentrickserie) (sorry only on German Wikipedia). See here for some images: http://www.zeichentrickserien.de/momo.htm

Comment: Wikipedia also has: 
Momo (2001) is an Italian animated film based on the novel. It is directed by Enzo D'Alò and features a soundtrack by Gianna Nannini, an Italian popular singer.[11] In 2003, a 26-episode animated television series based directly on this adaptation was released, serving as an extended re-telling of the film.